# The calculation results of coords and ci.coords in the pROC package are inconsistent. Which one should I choose?

Tags: r, roc

I have a set of data. When calculating with the `pROC` package, the sensitivity results obtained by `coords` and `ci.coords` are inconsistent. Which one should I choose? code show as below:

```
 g <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
           0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
           0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
           0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
           1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
           1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
           1, 1, 1, 1)
    
    d <- c(9, 3, 13, 6, 10, 8, 8, 13, 10, 6, 9, 12, 
           10, 4, 8, 6, 9, 14, 4, 7, 8, 14, 12, 6, 5,
           6, 12, 16, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 6, 15, 8, 10, 12,
           11, 12, 11, 8, 9, 7, 11, 14, 4, 16, 10, 4, 
           10, 12, 12, 2.7, 14, 11, 12, 12, 5, 8, 6, 6, 
           7, 8, 10, 2.3, 4, 5, 9, 8, 10, 16, 7, 11, 12,
           11, 5, 9, 9, 12, 8, 6, 6, 6, 7, 9, 5, 3)
    
    a <- roc(g, d)
    
    
    c1 <- coords(a, x = "best", best.policy = "random")
    se1 <- c1$sensitivity
    
    c2 <- ci.coords(a, x = "best", best.policy = "random")
    se2 <- c2$sensitivity
    se1
    se2
```

The results are as follows:

```
> se1
[1] 0.673913
> se2
          2.5%       50%     97.5%
[1,] 0.3478261 0.6521739 0.8913043
```

One of the sensitivity is 0.673913, the other is 0.6521739

Which result should I choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two values are representing two very different things.

`se1` is the sensitivity at the point with the highest youden index of the empirical ROC curve. You can see that the threshold is actually 8.5:

```
> c1$threshold
[1] 8.5
```

In contrast, with `ci.coords` you calculated the confidence interval of the "best" threshold:

```
> c2$threshold
     2.5% 50% 97.5%
[1,]  6.5 8.5  11.5
```

As you can see there is some uncertainty over what is the best threshold, with a 95% CI ranging between 6.5 and 11.5.

In turn, `se2` measures the uncertainty of the sensitivity at this moving threshold. The 50% value of 0.65 is the median sensitivity over 2000 bootstrap replicates (by default).

The fact that these two values aren't exactly identical isn't very surprising. Given the width of the confidence interval, I would claim they are essentially the same.